# Properties file in a java web application

Tags: java

I have a situation suppose I want to display hundreds of lines of string data in a jsp page based on some logic. So where do I save loads of string data in a String array, database or the property file? 
I have used properties file in a web application before to load the database properties and other stuff. 
But can anyone specifically tell me what are the properties files?
When to store data in the db & when to go for properties files?

Answer (score 2):

Properties File is normally used to read configuration for initial setup of your application as you have already mentioned.
XML based configuration files can 
also be used for the same purpose - reading initial configurations.

If you are saving logical data from a web application, I suggest use a DBMS, so that, you get advantage of the [ACID properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and DBMS systems supports reliable concurrent writes and reads.

Comment: thanks for the reply guys, much appreciated. One more thing if I add the string data to an array that means it will add to the heap size?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Properties file, when you know this is independent of
   application logic and can be changed at any point of time and the
   amount of data is very less
2. Use database, only when you are dealing with thousands of properties
   which can be retrieved based on certain logic

Comment: -1: You could have thousand of properties and still use a properties file. The usage of a database is when the data can change anytime and concurrently, while properties are meant to be loaded on app startup and must not change until app redeployment.

Comment: Database configuration can be a good solution even if you are not dealing with "thousands of properties", it depends on the usage.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, if you have million properties and using property file, is like walking on sword where the memory is highly wasted. It's not just suggestion I made, I have experimented with such options and then giving my feedback.

Comment: If they are properties, they're meant to be loaded into system on startup. If they're user properties or something that's not a system property, then it should be in database (but I can't find this kind of info in your answer). Also, the data in properties files doesn't change so often as database data does.

Answer (score 0):

If your properties are environment-specific (paths, connection identifiers...) you should go for a properties file. Because it's easy to manage one property file per platform, and because it avoids to have platform-specific data in your SQL dumps when you will restore the dump on a different platform.

If they are application logic data they definitely belong in the database.

If they are neither you probably can go for both, with a preference for the database in term of performance if you have as many as you say.

Also with a database a property change during runtime will be taken into account immediately, whereas with properties, if you don't parse the file everytime you read a property (which you should not if you have so many), property changes will happen only after an application restart.